# How To Declaratively Right Align a Column in a Dojo Datagrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a Dojo data grid created declaratively using html. I need to right align a column. I've tried the following two ways, I can't get it to work

**Try 1**

In the following example, he `align="right"` is ignored, but `width="100px"` is added to the style of each `<td>` element

```
<table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" style="height:100px;">
<thead>
   <tr>
    <th field="col1" width="auto">Col 1</th>
    <th field="col2" width="100px" align="right">Col 2</th>
    <th field="col3" width="100px" align="right">Col 3</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

**Try 2**

In the following example `style="text-align:right;"` seems to be completely ignored by dojo

```
<table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" style="height:100px;">
<thead>
   <tr>
    <th field="col1" width="auto">Col 1</th>
    <th field="col2" width="100px" style="text-align:right;">Col 2</th>
    <th field="col3" width="100px" style="text-align:right;">Col 3</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you want right aligned? The column itself? Or the text within the column?  I put together a quick fiddle to demonstrate the grid aping the dojo docs (http://jsfiddle.net/jrkeller/3h6MN/) but I don't think I understand what you're asking for.

Comment: @BuffaloBuffalo - I'd like the text within the columns to be right aligned. Col2 and Col3 have numbers with 2 decimal places. I want the decimals to line up.

Comment: @BuffaloBuffalo - Thank you for the jsfiddle, I was not able to right align the text there either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `styles` attribute on the `<th>` elements.  As the name suggests, This attribute specifies what css styles get applied to the `<td>`s for that column.

Example Markup:

```
<body class="claro">
    <table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" style="width:100%" store="myStore">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="col1" width="auto" align="left">Col 1</th>
                <th field="col2"  width="100px" align="left">Col 2</th>
                <th field="col3" width="100px" align="right" styles="text-align:right;">Col 3</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
```

Example js:

```
dojo.require('dojox.grid.DataGrid');
dojo.require('dojo.parser');
dojo.require('dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore');
dojo.ready(function() {
    var data = {
        identifier: 'id',
        items: []
    };
    var data_list = [
        {
        col1: "normal",
        col2: false,
        col3: 29.91},
    {
        col1: "important",
        col2: false,
        col3: 9.33},
    {
        col1: "important",
        col2: false,
        col3: 19.34}
    ];
    var rows = 60;
    for (var i = 0, l = data_list.length; i < rows; i++) {
        data.items.push(dojo.mixin({
            id: i + 1
        }, data_list[i % l]));
    }
    myStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: data
    });

    dojo.parser.parse();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jrkeller/3h6MN/1/

I discovered this attribute in the "Working With the Grid"  tutorial [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/working_grid/)

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'm embarrassed, I've gone through that tutorial for creating all my grids that I generate programatically and should have known better to simply just try it in declarative format as well.

Comment: It doesn't help that the attribute `styles` is incredibly unintuitive to put on an html element.